# Nothing displays for wifi connections

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, broadcom

I just installed ubuntu to my external HDD. This is the first time ive ever used ubuntu. Up until now ive only used windows. My problem is that i can not get my wifi to work on ubuntu. It works on windows (which is installed on my internal SSD) just fine, but it wont display anything on the ubuntu OS (on my external HDD). When i click on the dropdown menu in the top right corner, all i get are these options:

No Network Devices Available,
VPN Connections,
Enable Networking,
Connection Information,
Edit Connections

When i plug in my ethernet it works (currently using). Im not sure if im in need of a driver for my wifi adapter or what. Ill give pretty much any information needed, although i might need help how to determine it. My computer is a Dell Precision M3800 if that helps and the OS is Ubuntu 15.10. [Here is my wireless card details and the menu options i am given (top right faded)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukioT.png). Like i said, i am completely new to ubuntu so please break everything down into layman's terms and step-by-step. Thanks in advance!

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ap2M.png) is the code displayed when i run the terminal code `lspci -nn | grep 0280`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Ok @chili555 I added a screenshot of what i get when i input that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please get a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or wahtever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.